# Umbraco CMS: How to make a hit counter

Tags: c#, umbraco

I need to make a hit counter for Umbraco CMS. is there a way to do it? I would like to track popular articles and display them on the homepage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to implement this yourself, this doesn't come out of the box. Here's how you could go about it:

First of all you need to know what you want to be counting: The number of times an url is requested? Or he number of times a node is viewed (the same node may be available under several url's)? Hits or visits, should the counter go up if a user reloads a page?

For the actual implementation, you'll need three parts:

---

### 1. The  client request

Whenever a page is viewed which is supposed to be tracked, you'll need to trigger a request to the server which allows you to increment counter for that page.

There are several ways to achieve that, I recommend to do this by including a **picture request** (1px transparent gif).

For example:

```
<img src="/hits/4882/counter.gif" />
```

*4882* is the node id of the article page and is different on every article page.

You should probably include the code which generates the url on the master page (template).

---

### 2. The server-side handler

On the server side, you'll need a handler which responds to the picture request. A [*HttpHandler*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001) is perfect for this job. You can create it in a separate project, drop the dll in the bin folder and add the necessary web.config settings.

The handler has to do the following:

- **Identify from which url/node the picture request is coming from** - either by using the `HTTP_REFERRER` header of the request, or by using the information in the url (like the node id in the url of the image as in my example above).
- **Increment the counter** for that page - you'll need to add a table to the database, something simple with a column for the url or node id and a column with the number of requests should do.
- **Send back an image** and make sure, the client doesn't cache it (Set expires header etc.)

---

### 3. Displaying the most popular links

In order to display the top articles on a page, you'll need an Umbraco [user control](http://www.eyecatch.no/blog/my-first-umbraco-usercontrol-part-1-setting-up-visual-studio) which queries the table in the database and displays the most popular links.

Answer (score 1):

Blimey, is it the early 90's again? What about [Google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)?

Answer (score 1):

<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="counter.ascx.cs" Inherits="counter" %>

Code for the code behind:

C#

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.countMe();

        DataSet tmpDs = new DataSet();
        tmpDs.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"));

        lblCounter.Text = tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hits"].ToString();
    }

    private void countMe()
    {
        DataSet tmpDs = new DataSet();
        tmpDs.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"));

        int hits = Int32.Parse(tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hits"].ToString());

        hits += 1;

        tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hits"] = hits.ToString();

        tmpDs.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"));

    }
```

VB.NET

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Me.countMe()

        Dim tmpDs As New DataSet()
        tmpDs.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"))

        lblCounter.Text = tmpDs.Tables(0).Rows(0)("hits").ToString()
    End Sub

    Private Sub countMe()
        Dim tmpDs As New DataSet()
        tmpDs.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"))

        Dim hits As Integer = Int32.Parse(tmpDs.Tables(0).Rows(0)("hits").ToString())

        hits += 1

        tmpDs.Tables(0).Rows(0)("hits") = hits.ToString()

        tmpDs.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"))
    End Sub
```

Then you need to have an xml file in the root directory to make the code work as well. The XML file will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<counter>
  <count>
     <hits>0</hits>
  </count>
```